# MySQL add dynamic amount to an table

Tags: mysql, sql

i am very new to MySQL and making my first steps with it. I have right now 2 tables that look like this:

Event:

```
+-------+-------------+
| Field | Type        |
+-------+-------------+
| id    | int(11)     |
| name  | varchar(30) |
| date  | datetime    |
+-------+-------------+
```

User:

```
+----------+-------------+
| Field    | Type        |
+----------+-------------+
| name     | varchar(30) |
| amount   | int         |
+----------+-------------+
```

Now i would like to be able to add an dynamic amount of Users to an Event but i am not sure how i should create an dynamic table for that or how otherwise i should implement such an behaviour. What would be the best practice?

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: You might want to check out on table relations. There are different kinds of relationships (one Item that belongs to another other many items that belong to many others like a user that OWNS a comment and a post that has been visited by many users while many users have visited many posts). A very helpful tutorial for this is here: https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships--net-8561

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a classic many-to-many relation. You handle it by adding a new table

```
event_users table
-----------------
event_id
user_id
```

For an event (id=1) having two users (id=3,4) it looks like this

```
event_id | user_id
1        | 3
1        | 4
```

To get all users of an event you would do this

```
select u.name
from users u
join event_users eu on eu.user_id = u.id
join events e on eu.event_id = e.id
where e.name = 'my event'
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I didn't even know that it was a many-to-many relation. I will definitely read more of the different types of those.

Answer (score 2):

You need a third table, a *junction* table:

```
create table UserEvents (
    UserEventId int auto_increment primary key,
    UserId int,
    EventId int,
    constraint fk_userevents_userid foreign key (UserId) references Users(id),
    constraint fk_userevents_eventid foreign key (EventId) references Events(id)
);
```

Notes:

- I name tables in the plural.
- The id for the table is the singular followed by "id" (so I prefer `Users(UserId)` and `Events(EventId)`.
- This has declared foreign key relationships.
- If duplicates are not allowed, then you also want a unique constraint on `(UserId, EventId)`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer and also for the Notes. Those are some good tips for a beginner like me.

Comment: Please note that `constraint .... foreign key .... references  ....` only works when the defualt engine is InnoDB... if the defualt engine not is InnoDB you need to add `engine = InnoDB` to the create table statement.

Answer (score 1):

For this you should use a third table in which you should maintain event and related user id.

user_event

```
id    user_id   event_id    created_date
```

user_id and event_id  are foreign keys for this table and will point primary keys of user and event table respectively